# ASP.NET Core MVC - Add SelectList to index view containing items from Foreign Key linked table

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My understanding of how ASP.NET Core MVC is improving but some of the relational things still escape me.

Tool Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DV_ToolTrack.Models
{
    public class Tool
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(6, 2)")]
        [Display(Name = "Tool")]
        public decimal ToolNo { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(6, 2)")]
        [Display(Name = "OD")]
        public decimal? DFGOD { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(6, 2)")]
        [Display(Name = "ID")]
        public decimal? DFGID { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(6, 2)")]
        [Display(Name = "Thk")]
        public decimal? DFGThickness { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Shape")]
        public int ShapeId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ShapeId")]
        public virtual Shape Shape { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Drg Ref")]
        public string? DrgRef { get; set; }
        public string? Notes { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Shape Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DV_ToolTrack.Models
{
    public class Shape
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ToolVM Viewmodel (in ViewModels folder in Models)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DV_ToolTrack.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class ToolVM
    {
        public Tool Tool { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ShapeDropDown { get; set; }

    }
}
```

ToolTrackController

```
using DV_ToolTrack.Data;
using DV_ToolTrack.Models;
using DV_ToolTrack.Models.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DV_ToolTrack.Controllers
{
    public class ToolTrackController : Controller
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _db;
        public ToolTrackController(AppDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string Shape, string DrgRef, string Notes, string DFGOD, string DFGID)
        {
            var objList = from m in _db.Tools select m;                          
            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DFGOD))
            {
                objList = objList.Where(s => s.DrgRef.Contains(DFGOD));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DFGID))
            {
                objList = objList.Where(s => s.DrgRef.Contains(DFGID));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Shape))
            {
                objList = objList.Where(s => s.Shape.Type.Contains(Shape));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DrgRef))
            {
                objList = objList.Where(s => s.DrgRef.Contains(DrgRef));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Notes))
            {
                objList = objList.Where(s => s.Notes.Contains(Notes));
            }

            foreach (var obj in objList)
            {
                obj.Shape = _db.Shapes.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == obj.ShapeId);
            }

            return View(await objList.ToListAsync());
        }


        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ToolVM toolVM = new ToolVM()
            {
                Tool = new Tool(),
                ShapeDropDown = _db.Shapes.Select(i => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = i.Type,
                    Value = i.Id.ToString()
                })
            };
            return View(toolVM);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create(ToolVM obj)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.Tools.Add(obj.Tool);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Index View

```
@model IEnumerable<DV_ToolTrack.Models.Tool>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
}

<h1>ToolTrack</h1>

<form asp-controller="ToolTrack" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <div class="form-row pl-0 pb-3 ">
        <div class="col-1">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="DFGOD" placeholder="OD" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="DFGID" placeholder="ID" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Shape" placeholder="Shape" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="DrgRef" placeholder="Drg Ref" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Notes" placeholder="Notes" />
        </div>
        <div class="col text-right">
            <input class="btn btn-success mr-0" type="submit" value="Search" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DFGOD)
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DFGID)
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DFGThickness)
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Shape)
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DrgRef)
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Notes)
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ToolNo)
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.DFGOD
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.DFGID
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.DFGThickness
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Shape.Type
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.DrgRef
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Notes
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                        @item.ToolNo
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Location
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my mini project. As you can see, there is a rather simple form just showing what's in the database, where Tool is linked to Shape via a foreign key and shows the appropriate column on the index view.

My aim is to have some search facilities (which so far work ok (except for the decimal variables as I can't calculate on them, I 'think' it's because they're being seen as a string but understanding is limited))

I'd like to create a dropdown on the index view which lists all the entries as a search option from the Shape model Type column?

The DFGOD and DFGID in the model and in the database table are decimals, and a search I want to be able to perform is entering a decimal in either of the input boxes for example if I enter 105 in DFGOD, I want the results to be filtered to between (DFGOD - 1) and DFGOD, and if DFGID is also given a value, between DFGID and (DFGID + 1).

Would someone kindly point me in the right direction on this?

I know it's just a lack of clear understanding that has me in bits on this but any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I've followed tutorials this far to get me here.

Additionally I've seen some tutorials that use ViewBags but the tutorials I followed advised against the use of them as it should be 'strongly typed' which is why the ViewModel was created. Admittedly, I don't fully grasp why that is the case, or how it fully works.

Comment: It's unclear what part of your code is not behaving the way you want it to. Could you elaborate on what the problem is? You're also asking for how to do something in the view, but you haven't shown any view so far.

Comment: @Xerillio I've edited the post to include the Index view and added extra comments about what i'd like the app to do.